# How to create wildcard query with Elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I create a wildcard query with Elasticsearch? I tried below method but I think its not working(I mean it doesn't filter).

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("message", "ANG*"));
```

I also tried prefixQuery method but Its also didnt filter any result.

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("message", "ANG"));
```

**EDIT:**

```
        "_index": "log4j_2017",
        "_type": "log4j",
        "_id": "fd23123122",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
           "date": "2017-03-10T19:04:50.049Z",
           "contextStack": [],
           "level": "INFO",
           "marker": null,
           "thrown": null,
           "message": "ANGServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 2314 ms",
           "millis": 1489151090049,
           "contextMap": {},
           "threadName": "http-apr-8080-exec-77"
         }
```

Comment: Can you share your mapping please?

Comment: I am using log4j and I think it doesn't have any mapping.(dynamic mapping I think)

Comment: what do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?

Comment: @Val I don't have any access to es server. I can only send HTTP request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible reason is that you `message` field is analyzed, and it that case the tokens are indexed in lowercase, so you need to search like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("message", "ang*"));
```

or

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("message", "ang"));
```

Comment: Yes It worked when I use lowercase.I think I need to create a new mapping. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can we build wildcardQuery to match multiple terms in java?

Comment: @RameshPapaganti Feel free to create a new question with your exact needs

Answer (score 0):

**adding multiple wildcard in boolean query in java**

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(Constant.ELASTIC_ROOM_INDEX);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("roomNo", "*" + searchText + "*")).boost(2);
boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("location", "*" + searchText + "*")).boost(1);
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(boolQueryBuilder));
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
    Long roomId = ((Integer) sourceAsMap.get("roomId")).longValue();
    String roomNo = (String) sourceAsMap.get("roomNo");
    String location = (String) sourceAsMap.get("location");
    results.add(new SearchResultDTO(roomNo + ", " + location + ",Room", roomId));
}
```